# Why doesn't HAWQ support index for non-heap tables currently?

Tags: indexing, hawq

I wonder which difficulties it will consider in supporting index, such as index storage, index update, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the B+ tree index, I think the reason is that you can't implement it on HDFS. For the B+ tree, you have to change it frequently, but you can't update it after you closed your HDFS file.
HIVE support B+ tree index on HDFS, but the performance is really bad because it will rebuild the whole index after any row inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: What if implement the index on local filesystem. HAWQ 3.0 will support index for non-heap table. [HAWQ-303](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HAWQ-303).

Comment: Hawq doesn't support WAL log for user data, if you want to store index on local system you should implement WAL log to maintain index. But it's still not enough, if one of your segment is down, as the table is replicated to over datanode so you can still access to the table but you already lost your index. For the HAWQ-303 ticket, I don't think they are going to implement the index on local index.